# python - split iterable according string and make splits of same length

Tags: python, split, generator

I have a generator object like the following:

```
a = ["ab", "fasj", "sfk", "sfsfg", "ab", "gwre", "ab", "werwe", "fsfj", "lke"]
```

Using python, how do I split this according the occurrence of "ab" into chunks of the same length?

I am looking for something like:

```
b = ["ab", "fasj", "sfk", "sfsfg"]
c = ["ab", "gwre", " ", " "]
d = ["ab", "werwe", "fsfj", "lke"]
```

Comment: Do you know the maximum size of a "chunk" a priori?

Comment: Even sized and the maximum is 5?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was wrong. I ment strings of the same length. I correct this now.

Comment: I'm still unclear, does this mean that between occurrences of "ab" there will be no more than 4 other words? In otherwords, is the maximum length of an output list 5 (ab + 4 other words)?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code is not perfect but gets the job done (if I understood your problem correctly):

```
array = ["ab", "fasj", "sfk", "sfsfg", "ab", "gwre", "ab", "werwe", "fsfj", "lke"]

def split(l):
    def internal():
        stack = []
        for v in l:
            if v == "ab":
                if stack:
                    yield stack
                stack = []

            stack.append(v)

        if stack:
            yield stack

    ret = list(internal())
    size = max(map(len, ret))

    return [x + [" "] * (size - len(x)) for x in ret]   


print(split(array))
```

This will be returned:

```
[
    ["ab", "fasj", "sfk", "sfsfg"],
    ["ab", "gwre", " ", " "],
    ["ab", "werwe", "fsfj", "lke"]
]
```

Edit: OP has just stated that the maximum length until the next `ab` is 4. This is going to simplify the code drastically:

```
array = ["ab", "fasj", "sfk", "sfsfg", "ab", "gwre", "ab", "werwe", "fsfj", "lke"]

def split(l):
    stack = []
    for v in l:
        if v == "ab":
            if stack:
                yield stack + [" "] * (4 - len(stack))

            stack = []

        stack.append(v)

    if stack:
        yield stack + [" "] * (4 - len(stack))

print(list(split(array)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This code isn't very clean, but it may do the trick. Definitely verify it for yourself and see if it answers your question correctly.

```
listOfLists = []
newList = []
count = 0
for i in a:
    if i == "ab":
        if newList:
            listOfLists.append(newList)
        count = 0
        newList = [" "]*5
        newList[count] = i
        count += 1
    else:
        newList[count] = i
        count += 1
listOfLists.append(newList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Pythonic way of using `numpy.split`, and `list comprehension`:

```
import numpy as np
rslt = [list(x) for x in np.split(np.array(a), [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x=="ab"][1:])]
maxlen = max(len(x) for x in rslt)
rslt = [x+['']*(maxlen-len(x)) if len(x)<maxlen else x for x in rslt ]
```

**Explanation:**

```
In [149]: rslt = [list(x) for x in np.split(np.array(a), [i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x=="ab"][1:])]

In [150]: rslt
Out[150]: 
[['ab', 'fasj', 'sfk', 'sfsfg'],
 ['ab', 'gwre'],
 ['ab', 'werwe', 'fsfj', 'lke']]

In [151]: maxlen = max(len(x) for x in rslt)

In [152]: maxlen
Out[152]: 4

In [153]: rslt = [x+['']*(maxlen-len(x)) if len(x)<maxlen else x for x in rslt ]

In [154]: rslt
Out[154]: 
[['ab', 'fasj', 'sfk', 'sfsfg'],
 ['ab', 'gwre', '', ''],
 ['ab', 'werwe', 'fsfj', 'lke']]
```